# Can't access attributes in Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, model, laravel-5.7

Currently I have made a default Model for the database `user_domains`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Domains extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = true;
    protected $table = 'user_domains';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

}
```

So far, so good.

But, when I use the Query Builder to get some data from it, it won't allow me to access it via the attibutes, like $domains->domain

I've made a function and this one is using the `all` method to just get all data, without any difficult where-statements. But, the output of this is a huge collection with every detail of the database

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#274 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(App\Domains)#275 (26) {
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(12) "user_domains"
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["withCount":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["domain"]=>
        string(10) "example.nl"
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["verified"]=>
        int(1)
        ["created_at"]=>
        NULL
        ["updated_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["original":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["domain"]=>
        string(10) "example.nl"
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["verified"]=>
        int(1)
        ["created_at"]=>
        NULL
        ["updated_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["changes":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["casts":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dates":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dateFormat":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["appends":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["observables":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["relations":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["touches":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["timestamps"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["hidden":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["visible":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["guarded":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "*"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(App\Domains)#276 (26) {
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(12) "user_domains"
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["withCount":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["domain"]=>
        string(11) "example.com"
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["verified"]=>
        int(1)
        ["created_at"]=>
        NULL
        ["updated_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["original":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(2)
        ["domain"]=>
        string(11) "example.com"
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["verified"]=>
        int(1)
        ["created_at"]=>
        NULL
        ["updated_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["changes":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["casts":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dates":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dateFormat":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["appends":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["observables":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["relations":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["touches":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["timestamps"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["hidden":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["visible":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["guarded":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "*"
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    object(App\Domains)#277 (26) {
      ["incrementing"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["table":protected]=>
      string(12) "user_domains"
      ["primaryKey":protected]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["connection":protected]=>
      string(5) "mysql"
      ["keyType":protected]=>
      string(3) "int"
      ["with":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["withCount":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["perPage":protected]=>
      int(15)
      ["exists"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["attributes":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(3)
        ["domain"]=>
        string(11) "example.org"
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["verified"]=>
        int(1)
        ["created_at"]=>
        NULL
        ["updated_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["original":protected]=>
      array(6) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(3)
        ["domain"]=>
        string(11) "example.org"
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(1)
        ["verified"]=>
        int(1)
        ["created_at"]=>
        NULL
        ["updated_at"]=>
        NULL
      }
      ["changes":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["casts":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dates":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dateFormat":protected]=>
      NULL
      ["appends":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["dispatchesEvents":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["observables":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["relations":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["touches":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["timestamps"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["hidden":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["visible":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["fillable":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["guarded":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I just access the data from the table, instead of all this rubbish?

Comment: can you post your code, instead of all this!

Comment: and it is not allowing you to show the data as you are accessing it the wrong way. As far as i understand the data you get is an array and you are accessing it directly. Try printing `$domains[0]->domain`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$domains` is a `Collection` of `Domains`. not just one `Domain`.
You are trying to access an `attribute` of a `Domain` object from this `Collection`.

Since you haven't posted what you are trying to do in the question, I cannot provide an solution.

But I will share some knowledge.

get one element from the collection, and then you can access attributes of that object.

```
// name of the first domain (string)
$name = $domains->get(0)->name;
```

get all the names to another collection

```
// names of all the domains (another collection)
$names = $domains->map->name;
```